# Javascript: Check if classname exists

Tags: javascript, html, classname

```
<div class="Trade">
    <div id="Offer">
        <div class="NoResults">No Result!</div>
        <div class="FooterPager"> <span id="Offer"><a disabled="disabled">First</a>&nbsp;<a disabled="disabled">Previous</a>&nbsp;<a disabled="disabled">Next</a>&nbsp;<a disabled="disabled">Last</a>&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
function Check(){
return !(iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("Offer").firstElementChild.tagName.toLowerCase() == "table");
}
```

Is it possible to return a true or false value to check if the class "NoResult" exists? If so, how do I do it? You guys rocks. I can't change the HTML coding, only the javascript.

Answer (score 23):

Use `classList`.

```
var hasClass = element.classList.contains('some-class');
```

[Further Reading](http://blog.alexanderdickson.com/manipulating-classes-with-javascript) (disclaimer: link to my own post).

If not supported in your target platforms, then try...

```
var hasClass = (" " + element.className + " ").indexOf(" some-class ") > -1;
```

Comment: @Turnerj - Unfortunately, even IE9 doesn't support that :(

Comment: Ahhh, you're right it doesn't support it. For anyone else wanting to know support, [check it here](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList)

Comment: what is element? can do do `div.classList` ?

Comment: If `div` is a reference to a `HTMLElement`, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript without using a library like jQuery, you could do it by:

```
(' ' + MyElement.className + ' ').indexOf(' MyClassName ') != -1
```

This evaluates to true when "MyClassName" appears anywhere by itself inside the string as defined on the `className` property.

In your specific case, something like:

```
function Check()
{
    //Returns true when it exists
    return (' ' + iframe.contentDocument.getElementById('Offer').firstElementChild.className + ' ').indexOf(' NoResults ') != -1;
}
```

There was previously a mistake in my answer where it would incorrectly identify a partial match as pointed out in the comments. Basically, you need to consider in the check that the class name is whole. A neat way to do this (like the other answers show) is that if you spaces before and after both the entire `className` property and the class you are searching for, it will always find the whole class.

While this will work, I recommend [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16475733/1676444) as while `classList` [isn't available in every browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList) (<= IE9 and a few others), it is a neater solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( ~(' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' NoResult ') ) {
    // here you go. You've got that class...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to check if an element has a class for all browsers:
JQuery 1.6 or lower

```
    if($("#ElementId").attr('class').indexOf('ClassName') > -1)
```

JQuery 1.6 or higher

```
    if($("#ElementId").prop('class').indexOf('ClassName') > -1)
```

Or, if you are not going to use IE at all

```
    if($("#ElementId").prop('class').includes('ClassName'))
```