# Faster Method to determine whether an element with a class exists?

Tags: jquery

### Description:

I was trying to find out a method to check whether an element with specific class exists.

1. Then I encountered this code:

   ```
   if ($(".mydivclass")[0])
   {
      // Do something if class exists
   } 
   else 
   {
      // Do something if class does not exist
   }
   ```

   Which states that if there is a true value at the `first ([0])` index, then assume class exists.
2. Now again I can find another solution like:

   ```
   if ($(".mydivclass").size())
   {
        // code here
   }
   ```

   The `size()` method just returns the number of elements that the jQuery selector selects - in this case the number of elements with the class `mydivclass`. If it returns `0`, the expression is false, and therefore there are none, and if it returns any other number, the divs must exist.

So my question lies, **which one of these two is the faster one**?

Comment: Can you not just do `if($(".mydivclass"))`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if div with certain class name exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783280/check-if-div-with-certain-class-name-exists) also, in the answer you can find this: http://jsperf.com/check-if-div-exists

Comment: @JoelAlmeida, My question is which one is the faster one

Comment: Try it yourself: https://jsperf.com

Comment: For your information `size()` has been deprecated from `jquery 1.8`

Comment: Open the jsperf link and test . `$(".mydivclass")[0]` is fastest. http://jsperf.com/check-if-div-exists

Comment: @JoelAlmeida, Thanks... actualy you marked my question as duplicate.. But my question and the one you referred aren't the same.

Comment: @Saswat true. Can't remove the flag now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.mydivclass')[0]` is the fastest way.

**Sources**:

Performance test:

http://jsperf.com/check-if-div-exists

Related question:

[Check if div with certain class name exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783280/check-if-div-with-certain-class-name-exists)

Answer (score 0):

So I am curious also, and I did some test for following 5 methods:

1. $('.className')[0]
2. $('.className').size()
3. $('.className').length
4. document.querySelector('.className')
5. document.getElementsByClassName('className')[0]

my scripts:

```
var testCount = 100000;
var cn = 'container';
var cns = '.'+cn;
console.time('[0]');
for(var i=testCount;i>0;i--){
    if($(cns)[0]){};
}
console.timeEnd('[0]');

console.time('.size');
for(var i=testCount;i>0;i--){
    if($(cns).size()){};
}
console.timeEnd('.size');

console.time('.length');
for(var i=testCount;i>0;i--){
    if($(cns).length){};
}
console.timeEnd('.length');

console.time('querySelector');
for(var i=testCount;i>0;i--){
    if(document.querySelector(cns)){};
}
console.timeEnd('querySelector');

console.time('classname');
for(var i=testCount;i>0;i--){
    if(document.getElementsByClassName(cn)[0]){};
}
console.timeEnd('classname');
```

I do the test in this page, just pasting the code and run it in chrome console. And it turns out that the first 3 methods have similar performance, only difference by <100 ms.

querySelector method is fast when the class exist but slowest when class is not exist...Don't know why it is like this.

The getElementsByClassName method are fastest, only takes 1/10 time of the first 3 method.

this is one of the result:

```
[0]: 2168.198ms 
.size: 1951.075ms 
.length: 1936.117ms 
querySelector: 672.186ms 
classname: 242.048ms
```

and to answer your question, I think the two do not really have a faster one, both slow for this purpose...

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will always be faster because it's plain javascript and doesn't use jQuery at all. Plain javascript methods are always faster than jQuery.