# Change attrs with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, opacity, attr

I tried the following :

`$('div.tp-bullet').attr('style','opacity:.4');` and

```
$('.tp-bullet').attr('style','opacity:.4');
```

but it did not work.

[image]

What am I missing ?

Comment: Seems to work fine : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/sgcrupm8/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try use `.css` function to change the style like following :

```
$('div.tp-bullet').css('opacity','.4');
```

Comment: even $('div.tp-bullet').attr('style','opacity:.4'); would work , it's just that it is not an optimal way to do it as it would override any existing style attribute.

Comment: are you wrapping the code under $(document).ready if the dom is being loaded after script ?

Comment: @DinoMyte ya i know that, why not giving him an alternative to try it out. Anyway no luck

Comment: yes I am but this is not so simple as you show me, because I am using other script, (for one slider).this change some thing i dont use $ I use tpj(document) (what crazy).  tpj(document).ready(funcion(){alert("hello");}); works

Comment: So, you said that you have another version of jquery loaded as you're using naming conflix

Comment: is there some way for get same result using javascript pure?

Comment: @angel of course `document.querySelector("div.tp-bullet").style.opacity = '.4'`

Comment: not working, but may be the problem is the style to opacity to 1 is being set after my code  setting to .4 ( I am using the $(document).ready()) as I told this is tpj(document).ready();

Comment: Yes, there is something that intercept your code, do you have any async event used related to this code?

Comment: is there some way for something similar to when.cssclass exist? or easier when div with class tp-bullet exist then execute this code...??

Comment: I have tried this one  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5783355/586687  and I got "No exist"

Comment: also make sure no rule in css for opacity that is `!important`