# How to call javaScript function in blade template after errors count found in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have small laravel project and trying now on input validation using request. Below is my request file.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required', 
        'genericname' => 'required'
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
  return  [
        'name.required' => 'Name required',
        'genericname.required' => 'Genericname required'
  ]; 
}
```

My blade template work as normal to show flash once errors found as below code.

```
@if ($errors->count() > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        {{ $errors->first() }}
    </div>
@endif
```

But my concern is that, Is it possible to call javascript instead if errors found. For example of my need

```
@if ($errors->count() > 0)
    {{ callJavaScriptAlertFunction() }}
@endif
```

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: assuming `$errors->first()` shows an error class or element markup, alternatively, you could just invoke a javascript function when `$errors->first()`'s content is present. so you'd code that in js end

Comment: Dear Jack Bashford, Could you pls get more details for  ==> you could just invoke a javascript function when $errors->first()'s content is present<== Thanks

Comment: by the way, the comment above did not come from Jack Bashford :) here's an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/28059618/3859027

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use blade templates inside javascript. So create a function on document load.

assume you uses jQuery.

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        if({{ $errors->count() > 0 }}) {
            // your code goes here.
        }
    )
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this would work:

```
@if ($errors->count() > 0)
    <script>
        alert("Error: " + {{ $errors->first() }});
    </script>
@endif
```

Comment: came to meta here please https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384528/how-do-you-deal-with-an-edit-which-completely-changes-the-code-of-an-answer